# Sending strings over socket

Tags: java, python, sockets

So I'm trying to communicate via client/server using sockets between a raspberry pi and a laptop.  I've been able to send basic strings over using a simple python script on my pi to get the basic idea of how it worked.  Now I got a little more advanced and started using OpenCV along with a usb camera to make a little security system that detects motion in the frame of the camera.  I have the python script with the security system connect with the server and it is supposed to print out "Occupied" or "Unoccupied" in the console on my laptop in real time (eventually supposed to open a pop-up menu alerting that motion is detected) but it only prints out a long huge string of either "Occupied" or "Unoccupied" once I close the connection with my Pi.  Why isn't it printing out in real time?  Here is the java code on my laptop, unforunately my Pi is in school at the moment and I can't access the python code but I will post it tomorrow.

```
public class PyComms {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try{
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4444);
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port 4444");
            while(true){
                Socket connected = server.accept();
                System.out.println("CONNECTED WITH CLIENT");
                BufferedReader inFromPi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connected.getInputStream()));
                while(true){
                    String fromclient = inFromPi.readLine();

                    if(fromclient.equalsIgnoreCase("Occupied")){
                        System.out.println("Client responded with "+fromclient + "\n");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Client responded with "+fromclient + "\n");
                        connected.close();
                    }
                }

            }   

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);

        }


    }

 }
```

Comment: Putting aside the less-than-ideal usage of `while(true)`... what output are you getting?  Is it printing out any of those messages?

Comment: @childofsoong it prints out a long string of "Client responded with OccupiedOccupiedOccupiedOccupiedOccupied..." or "Client responded with UnoccupiedUnoccupiedUnoccupiedUnoccupiedUnoccupied.."

Comment: most likely the important side is the python code, and most likely you are not flushing the socket when you send a message.

Comment: also, are you including a newline after each message? (`readLine()` reads until it gets a newline)

Comment: @jtahlborn - on the python side there is no flush if you use `send`/`recv`. `flush` only comes into play if you create a file object wrapper for the socket.

Comment: my python code sends via `client_socket.send(text)`  where text would either be Occupied or Unoccupied

Comment: Have you followed up on @jtahlborn's `readLine` comment? 99% chance that's your problem.

Comment: I'll implement it, thanks.  By that I assume you mean in my sending via python by adding a new line return ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was exactly what @jtahlborn said.  All I had to do was include a new line after each message was sent in the python code.  I achieved this by doing something similar to `client_socket.send(text+'\n')`